# abcde cd ripping from flac+cue without CDDB info?

Tags: ripping, abcde

I have a CD which isn't in the CDDB database, but which has cdtext information. I used [Abcde](http://lly.org/~rcw/abcde/page/) with `abcde -1` to create a whole-disc FLAC file plus cuesheet (for archiving), and now later want to split it into individual compressed files to use on my phone.

The first step works fine, and creates a cue file including track information. However, when I use `abcde -d myalbum.flac`, I get the response that there is no CDDB info. Is there a way to tell it to just read from the cue file?

This same basic problem crops up when the CD has extended parts not ripped into the FLAC file — data tracks, for example — because the CDDB info doesn't match. But the cue file is *right there* — can the program be told or tricked into reading the info from there?